# How to add search bar to menu bar in magento2

Tags: magento2, theme, search-type

How to add search bar to menu bar in Magento2?

With file structure details explained.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to move the search bar to the menu.

In `theme_dir/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <move element="top.search" destination="store.menu" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

You need to work with the css to get it to display the way you want. For example in `theme_dir/web/css/source/_extend.less`:

```
.block-search {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.nav-sections-item-content {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: By adding above code no changes were done so i used this below line  <move element="top.search" destination="catalog.topnav" after="-"/>

Comment: The code in the original answer worked for me.  However, it removes the search block from the main page (because it moves it to the mobile menu).